# Training a classifier on mismatched length dataset SciKit Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am working with a dataset similar to the following:

X_values (a list of x,y,z coordinates):

```
[

   [(32.0, 22.0, -2.0), (32.0, 22.0, -2.0), (28.0, 50.0, 6.0), (28.0, 14.0, 56.0), (-26.0, 56.0, 6.0), (-18.0, 50.0, 4.0), (14.0, -36.0, 50.0), (-16.0, -70.0, -6.0), (-14.0, -6.0, 4.0), (18.0, -46.0, -28.0), (28.0, 12.0, 54.0), (28.0, 12.0, 54.0), (-26.0, 62.0, 12.0), (-28.0, 55.0, 5.0), (46.0, -76.0, 6.0), (-30.0, -88.0, 28.0), (-8.0, -70.0, -4.0), (50.0, -58.0, -16.0), (-30.0, -88.0, 28.0), (14.0, -40.0, 50.0), (40.0, -76.0, -2.0), (-64.0, -54.0, -4.0), (10.0, -16.0, 44.0), (14.0, 0.0, 6.0), (14.0, 0.0, 6.0), (-12.0, -4.0, 0.0), (14.0, 0.0, 6.0), (30.0, 22.0, -6.0), (30.0, 22.0, -6.0), (-30.0, 60.0, 12.0), (-26.0, 58.0, 4.0)]
   ...
]
```

Y_values (a list of descriptors):

```
[ 
   ['Aged', 'Aged, 80 and over', 'Cognition', 'Dopamine', 'Female', 'Humans', 'Image Processing, Computer-Assisted', 'Magnetic Resonance Imaging', 'Male', 'Memory, Short-Term', 'Middle Aged', 'Neostriatum', 'Neuropsychological Tests', 'Positron-Emission Tomography', 'Psychomotor Performance', 'Radiopharmaceuticals', 'Tyrosine']
   ...
]
```

Each list in the X_values corresponds to the list at the corresponding index of the Y_values. I am trying to create a classifier for the X_valyes based on the terms (or vice-versa) but I am not able to isolate a relationship between a single coordinate and a single term. I attempted to run the K_nearest neighbors classifier with Sci-kit learn:

```
knn.fit(train_points, train_descriptors)
```

But I believe the error stems from the mismatched columns. Is there a better classification algorithm that I could apply to this dataset based on these parameters?

Comment: Is there a huge number of categories? (descriptors)

Comment: Yes, there are a little over 400 descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

I consider the best way to model your problem is separating the coordinate and treat them as multiple features. Let me use Linear Regression to explain how can it help.

Suppose that your features are `X`, `Y`, `Z` then you would have for the first training example (32.0, 22.0, -2.0) and I'll call the learning parameters(weights) `theta` the following hypothesis:

`h(x) = theta_1 * X + theta_2 * Y + theta_3 * Z + bias_term`

This will represent the hypothesis for the first set of parameters but if you can to generalize it then you convert the training examples (**Input**) in a matrix with vector columns:

`X' = [ X Y Z]`

Now it seems you are trying to model it as a supervised learning problem as you have labels for your data. For a KMeans problems you will have something like this

```
X = np.array([[32.0, 22.0, -2.0],[...],[...]])
knn = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors= NUM_CLUSTERS, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(X)
```

Answer (score 0):

This task may be suitable for a Decision Tree Classifier, you can check the details of use [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html). But it is pretty straightforward, something like this:

```
from sklearn import tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X_values , Y_values )
```

where X_values and Y_values are the arrays you described.

You can also try to use one-hot encoding to transform your labels to arrays of 0s and 1s and then train a Neural Network with a mean square loss function or categorical loss entropy, but it may need a lot of data to avoid overfitting. Both MLP and one-hot encoding are implemented on sklearn. Check [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) and [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html).